# Adding items under a specific category using Sonata Admin

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

Using Symfony2, i followed a tuto how to make sonata admin bundle to manage products in a shop, it's working fine, i can add, delete, modify each product (each product contain these colums: id, name, price, quantity)
Now my question how can i add categories for these products? In sonata admin I want to be able to select a defined category before adding a product into it (kind of drop-down-menu, is it possible?) so i can easly manage products.
Also I want to be able to manage categories from the same admin dashboard (add/remove/modify).

(I just started using Symfony2, I'm a beginner I need a clear explanation & thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Category entity, and a CategoryAdmin class. Then in your product Entity, you will be able to add a OneToMany *link*, something like :

```
class Project
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="categories")
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
    */
    private $categories;
}
```

Then in your admin, you'll need to have a look on the [sonata_type_collection](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection), which allow one-to-many connection :

> The `Collection Type` is meant to handle creation and editing of model
>   collections. Rows can be added and deleted, and your model abstraction
>   layer may allow you to edit fields inline. You can use `type_options` to
>   pass values to the underlying forms.

Good luck !

Comment: Still getting an error:
The current field `category` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``
500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

Need help, thanks

Comment: Yep, you need to create a CategoryAdmin class, even if it's incomplete.